# Как соеденить два этих div'a линией по клику

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

У меня есть два div'a. Они перемещаются по нажатию мышки. Я хочу, чтобы на дивах была точка, которая бы позволяла по нажатию протянуть линию до следующего. От "стартового" к "ожиданию" и так далее, может быть, к нескольким? Как это можно сделать? Объясните пожалуйста

Вот моя верстка

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable");

function dragAndDropAllNodes() {
  let mover = false,
    x,
    y,
    posX,
    posY,
    first = true;

  [].forEach.call(elements, function(item) {
    item.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
      mover = true;
    });
    item.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
      mover = false;
      first = true;
    });
    item.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
      mover = false;
      first = true;
    });
    item.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
      if (mover) {
        if (first) {
          x = e.offsetX;
          y = e.offsetY;
          first = false;
        }
        posX = e.clientX - x;
        posY = e.clientY - 60 - y;

        this.style.left = posX + "px";
        this.style.top = posY + "px";
      }
    });
  });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", dragAndDropAllNodes);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  overflow: auto;
  /* добавить полосу прокрутки */
}

header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: white;
}

.wrap {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-link {
  padding: 1.1em;
}

.header-h1 {
  padding-left: 1em;
}

#header-title {
  color: #1c5a7d;
}

.header-link>a {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #888;
}

.header-link>a:hover {
  color: #444;
}

.header-menu-wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

header-h1 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 26px;
  float: right;
}

.botmaker-container {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.botmaker-node {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 230px;
  max-height: 130px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 120px;
  border-top-right-radius: 120px;
}

.node-form-input {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 170px;
}

.draggable {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100px;
  cursor: move;
}

.botmaker {
  min-height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.socket.number {
  background: #96b38a
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div id="header-title" class="">
      <h1 class="header-h1">Visual bot maker</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="header-menu-wrapper">
      <div class="wrapper-item header-link">
        <a href="">DOCUMENTATION</a>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper-item header-link">
        <a href="">FORUM</a>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper-item header-link">
        <a href="">SUPPORT</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<section class="botmaker-container dragscroll">
  <div class="botmaker">

    <div class="botmaker-node start-node draggable" style="cursor: move; left: 200px; top: 129px;">
      <form action="" method="post" class="form-group">
        <div class="node-form-input">
          <label for="startNode">Стартовый узел</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startNode" placeholder="Start phrase">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary node-submit">Ок</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="botmaker-node regular-node draggable" style="cursor: move; left: 500px; top: 129px;">
      <form action="" method="post" class="form-group">
        <div class="node-form-input">
          <label for="regularNode">Узел ожидания</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id='regularNode' placeholder="Start phrase">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary node-submit">Ок</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант отрисовывать линию через библиотеку Snap.svg. Примерно так: [пример](https://codepen.io/Lukyanenko/pen/XPNORB?editors=1111)

```
var s = Snap(500, 200);
var isDraw = false,
  line;

// Определение координат мыши__________________
var mouse = {
  getX: function(e) {
    return e.offsetX;
  },
  getY: function(e) {
    return e.offsetY;
  }
};
//_____________________________________________

s.mousedown(function(e) {
  isDraw = true;
  line = s.line(mouse.getX(e), mouse.getY(e), mouse.getX(e), mouse.getY(e));
  line.attr({
    stroke: 'black'
  });
});

s.mousemove(function(e) {
  if (isDraw) {
    line.attr({
      x2: mouse.getX(e),
      y2: mouse.getY(e)
    });
  }
});

s.mouseup(function(e) {
  isDraw = false;
});
```

Ну и добавить событие которое будет понимать что вы соединили две точки и сохранять или удалять лини.

Comment: `добавить событие которое будет понимать что вы соединили две точки и сохранять или удалять лини.` а это тоже делается через библиотеку snap.svg? Просто не хватает знаний как это реализовать все, непонятно, что прочесть нужно и все в таком духе